# Converting HTML table to excel sheet using C#

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have html table in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem body and I just need to fill excel sheet with this table using C# for desktop application. Could any one help me in this regard. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A quick and dirty way:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Temp\Table.xls", mailItem.Body);
```

Excel will open it even though the file does not contain a valid xls document

Comment: But it will issue a warning on load, at least in Excel 2010

Comment: It does fill the excel sheet except few columns contain hyperlinks :(.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the e-mail and [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) to write to Excel (only 2007/2010 xlsx version).